# CloudCannon visual editor is not working?

Tags: jekyll, liquid, cloudcannon

I have a Jekyll website  deployed on netlify and I use CloudCannon to make a "template" of my site. I followed this [tutorial](https://learn.cloudcannon.com/jekyll/client-editable-jekyll-sites/) but when I add `class="editable"` the visual editor doesn't let me save the changes when I change any of the text (The save button is disabled). This doesn't happen when I update the title of the page in the right panel for example.

This is how the page is shown:

[image]

And this is the code of it (I have the header and footer in a `default.html` layout):

```
---
layout: default
title: Inicio
permalink: /
---

<header>
    <div class="header-content editable">
        <div class="header-content-inner editable">
            <h1 class="editable">
                Esta es la p&aacute;gina de inicio del portal de jekyll y liquid
            </h1>
            <hr />
            <p class="editable">
                Este sitio web es un ejemplo del uso de jekyll 
            </p>
            <a class="editable btn btn-primary btn-xl page-scroll" href="/about.html">¿Quieres saber más?</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<aside class="bg-dark">
    <div class="container text-center editable">
        <div class="call-to-action editable">
            <h2 class="editable">
                &iquest;Quieres ver lo que te ofrecemos? 
            </h2>
            <a class="editable btn btn-default btn-xl wow tada" href="/services.html">Mira nuestros servicios</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</aside>
```

I added the `class="editable"` into every tag attempting to make it work because the class was working nowhere.

I cannot provide the site.

Comment: You might want to start with NOT nesting divs that contain the editable class. That will go wrong/cause errors for sure. What happens when you remove all editable classes and update the title in the right pane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have nesting divs that contain the editable class. That causes an error. Remove all editable classes and add just one on a single h2. That will fix your problem.